# Error while installing fuzzywuzzy library in my jupyter notebook

Tags: python, string, installation, nlp, fuzzywuzzy

When i am trying to install `fuzzywuzzy`library in my jupyter notebook,
i am getting below error.

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to 
proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication 
Required',))': /simple/fuzzywuzzy/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to 
proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication 
Required',))': /simple/fuzzywuzzy/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to 
proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication 
Required',))': /simple/fuzzywuzzy/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to 
proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication 
Required',))': /simple/fuzzywuzzy/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to 
proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication 
Required',))': /simple/fuzzywuzzy/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fuzzywuzzy (from 
versions: )
No matching distribution found for fuzzywuzzy
```

Could anyone please help me ??

Comment: did you solve this issue? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `pip install --proxy https://username:pwd@proxy:host fuzzywuzzy`